# Problems deploying jhipster app to heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, jhipster

I'm trying to deploy a jhipster based app to heroku using the heroku subgenerator. Everything works and the app is deployed but it seems that the database is not properly configured (using Mysql). The thrown error is the following:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Heroku database URL is not configured, you must set $JDBC_DATABASE_URL
```

Cannot find a solution in the documentation.
Maybe i'm missing some configuration before deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the database wasn't added, which is probably due to [this bug](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3993). You can confirm by running `heroku addons` from the same directory you ran `yo jhipster:heroku`.

In any case, you can probably correct this by running:

```
$ heroku addons:create jawsdb:kitefin
```

Comment: That solved the problem @codefinger, you were right that the addon was not properly added.  Thanks a lot!