# Heroku error on deployment of a Jhipster App: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I'm having this problem everytime my jhipster app starts. I deployed in heroku (prod).

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/app/build/libs/spingular-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/spingular/web/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4de025bf' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4de025bf': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[com/spingular/web/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Please, let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: Looks like the URL of your datasource is wrong or refers to a variable that is not set.

Comment: Thanks Gaël, how can I fix that?

Comment: I haven't used Heroku for at least one year but I remember that few new users forgot to give their credit card number to get a working database even if it's a free plan. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562616/problems-deploying-jhipster-app-to-heroku

Comment: They have my credit card ;-)